# Access Android Market through SSH tunnel

Tags: android, ssh, google-play, ssh-tunnel

My mobile provider firewalls me from downloading applications from the Android market. So what I am trying to is to tunnel all traffic to the Android Market through an SSH connection. A [quick search](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android%20Market/thread?tid=011f8c3c93e8953b&hl=en) told me that apps are downloaded using port 5228. Thus, I followed those steps:

1. Create an SSH tunnel on dynamic port 5228 using the [ConnectBot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/) application
2. On the server side: `tcpdump port 5228`
3. Download from Android markert

Step 2 does not produce any output, and the app download fails. Therefore, either the Android Market uses another port, or I am doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: Entirely random question: which provider is this?

Comment: Trying using market.android.com, register your phone and push apps from there.  It may use the same port but it's worth a try.

Comment: It's a French provider, called SFR. Generally speaking, French phone providers are known for their "unconventional" practices.

Comment: SFR claims to support the Android Market: http://www.sfr.fr/telephonie-mobile/services-options/services-smartphones/os/android/index.html  Got any links demonstrating the contrary?

Comment: SFR got "Unlimited" (Illimythics 3G+) and "Unlimited Full Internet" data plans. The former doesn't allow for download from Android Market. Plenty of forum threads complaining about that, e.g: http://forum.frandroid.com/topic/6376-help-android-market-forfait-sfr-illimythics-3g-et-pas-de-wifi/

Comment: Does the network on your Android device have highly restricted and/or monitored internet access? Looking for a simple and easy solution to your deprivation or lack of online privacy? SSH Tunnel for Android is a free, simple tool that provides secure, encrypted web access on your device via SSH (Secure Shell) tunneling. The app allows you to enable SSH tunneling selectively as well as globally, that is, you can enable tunneling for individual apps of your choice or for every app on your device with a single tap.

Comment: Did you try Haphazard's suggestion?

Comment: @Robin: Yes, I did. App pushing does not work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/enjoy-secure-unrestricted-internet-access-with-ssh-tunnel-for-android/) seems like a viable option.  There are options to route all traffic through the tunnel or individual applications.  As well there is an Enable Market option (although the details specify that this is for users in China).

The downside is that you need root for this to be fully functional.  Otherwise all you can do is setup a SOCKS proxy on a local port, which you can already do with ConnectBot.  At the end of the day if you are trying to get around your carrier restrictions odds are you will eventually need to root your device.

If you are interested you can grab the app directly from [here](http://code.google.com/p/sshtunnel/) and load it directly on your phone.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This solution works great! Both on Wifi and 3G, with an SSH server listening on port 443. For the sake of completeness, do you happen to know how this app works? i.e: how could I reproduce the same behaviour using a command-line tool?