# Direct ALL android traffic through SSH tunnel

Tags: android, linux, ssh, iptables, cyanogenmod

I am trying to completely conceal all traffic on my phone from the wireless provider.

I would like to do this by directing the traffic through an SSH tunnel to my home router through iptables (not sure if they help?).

The phone is rooted and is running CyanogenMod 7.1 (and is therefore iptables-capable).

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284217/access-android-market-through-ssh-tunnel), but I am still sort of shaky on the details.
That question sort of describes how to do this for a single port - but how can I do this for every single packet on every single port?

This question is of both practical and academic interest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [sshtunnel](http://code.google.com/p/sshtunnel/)? Iptables alone is not enough to do this.

As for an overview of how it's actually done:

1. Login to your server with ssh and forward the HTTP proxy port to the Android device. Thus any traffic going to `localhost:3128` will actually go to the remote machine (your home router).
2. Because Android doesn't have a global proxy setting, you make redirect all traffic going to port 80 (and 443 for HTTPS) to `localhost:3128`. That's where iptables comes in:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to localhost:3128`

If you want to redirect other protocols too, you use a SOCKS proxy with a similar setup. To redirect DNS, redirect port 53 through the tunnel, etc.

All in all to complete conceal 'all traffic' is not that easy, so just use the app. If you want to patch Cyanogenmod to do this, look at the source and modify the startup scripts.

Comment: I have not, because this is just an app that runs in userspace. I want to encrypt every single packet starting from boot and ending in shutdown. With that app, packets would go through the carrier as normal until I enable the app.

Comment: In that case you need to build your own firmware. Look at sshtunnel source, check what commands it is running (setting up the tunnel, running, the proxy, redirection, etc), and add those to the startup scripts. The 'userspace' part is just the GUI to kickstart the whole process. Essentially it's a transparent proxy, and iptables is used just to redirect all traffic to the proxy.

Comment: BTW, it does have an 'Auto connect' option, the would enable the tunnel once network is available, so you don't actually have to run the app manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll do this over the weekend and post my findings.

Comment: this rule only redirect 80. Unable to redirect port 443

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't solve your use case because this only directs the traffic of firefox, but **you don't need root**.

---

## TL;DR

1. Install [Termux](https://termux.com/) app on android, **EDIT IMPORTANT:** [Termux does not receive updates on Play Store anymore](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Termux-and-Android-10). Install the application and add-ons from F-Droid instead.
2. In termux install openssh `pkg i -y openssh`
3. ssh into server using *dynamic port forwarding* `ssh user@server -D12345`
4. Install [Firefox Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox_beta) on android (at this time, plain Firefox doesn't support configuring with `about:config`)
5. Open Firefox Beta, and go to `about:config`
6. Search `proxy`
7. Look for and set the following properties:

   ```yaml
   network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost: true
   network.proxy.socks: localhost
   network.proxy.socks_port: 12345
   network.proxy.type: 1
   ```

   make sure `network.proxy.socks_port` matches with the port in the ssh command above
8. Done!, you are now navigating through the ssh server on Firefox

---

## Full instructions using ssh-keys

### Usage

1. Open Termux and run `ssh user@server -D12345` (or just press <kbd>Up</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> if you have run this command previously)
2. Navigate using the proxy-configured Firefox
3. Done!, your traffic is going through the server

### Install

#### Setup Android

##### Termux

1. Install [Termux](https://termux.com/)
2. Configure ssh client by running the following commands:

   ```sh
   # Ask for storage permission
   termux-setup-storage &&
   # Install openssh
   apt install -y openssh &&
   # Generate an SSH key
   ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa &&
   # Set a password for the private key
   # Get public key
   echo -e '\nCopy the following public key:'
   cat ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub
   ```
3. (Optional) If you have access to the server with ssh, then run:

   ```sh
   ssh-copy-id user@server
   ```

   If not, you need to manually add the public key to the server. This is explained below in the **Setup server** section

##### Firefox

1. Install [Firefox Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox_beta) - normal firefox might work if you can access to `about:config`
2. Open Firefox and go to the url `about:config`, search `proxy` and set the following configurations:

   ```yaml
   network.proxy.allow_hijacking_localhost: true
   network.proxy.socks: localhost
   network.proxy.socks_port: 12345
   network.proxy.type: 1
   ```

   make sure `network.proxy.socks_port` matches with the port used in the ssh command in the **Usage** section

#### Setup server

If you succesfully run the command `ssh-copy-id` there's nothing to do here.
But if not, you need to manually add the public key generated:

```sh
echo 'public key' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

---

In the future I will be keeping this up-to-date here: [https://github.com/madacol/knowledge/blob/master/Ssh%20poor-man's-vpn%20on%20android.md](https://github.com/madacol/knowledge/blob/master/Ssh%20poor-man%27s-vpn%20on%20android.md)

Comment: Very nice! Firefox Beta having proxy settings is a game changer!